# Is it possible to set the Magento checkout success to another page?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, checkout

The website of a client is using an extension for it's payments. The creator of this extension has set the success page of the payments to a CMS-page.

There is one payment method left, which is handled by Magento itself. This payment method ends up on the standard checkout/success page. Is it possible to get that payment method to end up on the same CMS page?

The reason that is wanted is because on the CMS page, cart tracking has been implemented, and the client wants to be able to influence the page content, title and url herself.

Answer (score 2):

Just implement an observer, listening to `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_success` (check the eventname!)

And then redirect via:

```
$e = new Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Exception();
$e->prepareForward('index','error','honeyspam');
throw $e;
```

An example can for the [Observer can be find in HoneySpam](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/HoneySpam/blob/master/app/code/community/Hackathon/HoneySpam/Model/Observer.php#L58%3aL68) and the definition for the [event is as always](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/HoneySpam/blob/master/app/code/community/Hackathon/HoneySpam/etc/config.xml#L71%3aL78) (be careful, this listens to customer_create!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've tried it using this method, however, I have not managed to get the observer working. Though this might be due to my lack of experience with observers. I might check out the working of this some more. Thank you for your time so far.